# Should a more recent answer be on top or bottom (all else equal)?

Tags: discussion, support, answers, sorting

I posted an answer to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29175345/repository-variable-usage-how-to-track) about 2 or so hours after a different answer was posted. I thought that if all things are equal (same number of up votes, down votes etc) they would show in order of the time of the answer, or by whatever filter you were applying (votes, newest, oldest, etc). What I see happening is more random. On this single question, sometimes when I look at it my answer is on top, and sometimes my answer is on bottom.

If all things are equal, does the system just randomly assign one answer to be on top? See screenshots for my example

**My answer on top:**
[image: Mine on top]

**My answer on bottom:**
[image: Mine on bottom]

Answer (score 10):

When ordering by votes, answer posts with an equal score are listed in *arbitrary* random order, yes. Post age doesn't come into this.

This is by design to give answers with an equal score an equal amount of attention.