# Why aren't answers of equal score displayed chronologically?

Tags: discussion, answers, sorting

I would have expected answers of equal score on a question to be displayed in the order they were posted.

This makes sense especially on questions where multiple users reply within a relatively short span of time.

Why should users who posted their answer later (and could have read the existing ones) have the benefit of their answers being read first by the question author when (s)he gets back to the question?

Comment: One word: [FGITW](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18014/what-is-fgitw-and-scite).

Comment: Shouldn't FGITW be rewarded and displayed first when answer has equal score with later ones?

Comment: No, of course not. It should be displayed lower, because it has had more time to attract upvotes, but didn't.

Comment: I see your point. Ok, that makes sense. But this encourages people to reformulate existing answers and get the credit, because the OP reads the first answer in the list, tries the solution, and no longer looks past that answer (they already found the solution).

Comment: The sorting of answers has been discussed to death before, but I do not have the time now to search for the (duplicate) questions.

Comment: I understand. I only did a quick search and didn't find anything that seemed similar to mine. I'll refine my search. Thank you for your time. A Happy New Year!

Comment: @Glorfindel: Maybe a good starting point: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17624/294055. The term SCITE is coined in one of the answers which describes the "reformulation" problem mentioned by Andrei.

Comment: [Here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288568/should-a-more-recent-answer-be-on-top-or-bottom-all-else-equal) is a possible duplicate, but this discussion is so old most of it is on Meta Stack Exchange, like the link @honk mentioned. Happy New Year to y'all!

Comment: Thank you for the linked resources. I'll keep reading.

Comment: I keep running into **"if your answer is better, it will go up regardless"** as an argument. I'm talking about answers that are more or less the same technical solution, reformulated. The fact they came later to the party is hardly noticeable, especially for users who are not very experienced on SO. Basically, the system now rewards people who just go to the second page of questions and reformulate existing answers. I bet anyone here I can make 100 rep/day on technologies I have no clue about just because I have decent English skills. How can this be a good thing?

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu Do you have an example of this actually happening?

Comment: @Yannis No. I find police work on SO utterly unattractive. But this happened to me twice over the past week (and it's why I asked this in the first place): I had a few hours I decided to dedicate to SO. I answered quality answers, explaining principles too, like I usually do. Another user also active on the same technology would post more concise (shorter) answers after a while and their answer got picked. Maybe they didn't copy my answer, but it was clearly there when they posted. I like helping out, not pointing fingers. So I left, giving up on the remaining time of my break.